Как правильно указать реакцию? Telegram Bot Aiogram Python
Создаю простого бота в телеграмме на Python, использую библиотеку Aiogram 3.7.0.0. нигде не могу найти, как правильно использовать функцию bot.set_message_reaction(), а именно как указать нужную мне реакцию? я бы хотел использовать реакцию "", в unicode она "U+1F44C".
Пример из кода:
await bot.set_message_reaction(message.chat.id, message.message_id, reaction="")

Полный код функции:
# Обработчик команды "/checkid"
@dp.message(Command("checkid"), F.chat.type.in_({"group", "supergroup"}))
async def checkid(message: types.Message):
  user_id = message.from_user.id
  chat_id = message.chat.id
  current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

  try:
    # Проверяем, является ли пользователь администратором группы или владельцем группы
    member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=user_id)
    if member.status == "administrator" or member.status == "creator":
      # Отправляем ID чата в личные сообщения
      await bot.send_message(
        chat_id=user_id,  # Отправляем сообщение в личные сообщения
        text=f"ID этого чата: <code>{chat_id}</code>",
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
      )
      # Ставим реакцию "" на сообщение администратора
      await bot.set_message_reaction(message.chat.id, message.message_id, reaction="") # Как правильно указать реакцию?
    else:
      await message.reply("У вас нет прав администратора или владельца в этой группе.")
  except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"@{message.from_user.username} ({message.from_user.id}): {e}")
    await message.reply("Произошла ошибка.")


я нашел решение:
await bot.set_message_reaction(message.chat.id,
  message.message_id, 
  reaction=[{"type": "emoji", "emoji": ""}])

